# Null Behavior in Pandas DataFrame Multiplication

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame of values to questions, `vals`, and a DataFrame of the weights to those questions `multiply_vals`. Each record in the `vals` DataFrame corresponds to a single user.

```
import pandas as pd
vals = pd.DataFrame({'A1':[0,1], 'A2':[1,2], 'A3':[3,3],'A4':[4,2],'B1':[2,1]})
multiply_vals = pd.DataFrame({'Weights':[.5,.25,.75,1,.33]}, index=['A1','A2','A3','A4','B1'])

#vals
   A1  A2  A3  A4  B1
0   0   1   3   4   2
1   1   2   3   2   1

#Multiply Vals
    Weights
A1     0.50
A2     0.25
A3     0.75
A4     1.00
B1     0.33
```

I want to multiply each row in `vals` by the correct weight `multiply_vals`, but there seems to be some unexpected results with nulls.

Expected result:

```
    A1    A2    A3  A4    B1
0  0.0  0.25  2.25   4  0.66
1  0.5  0.50  2.25   2  0.33
```

What I tried:
I tried using [`mul`/`multiply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.multiply.html) as well as combining it with [`transpose`/`T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) but it returns nulls.

```
vals.mul(multiply_vals.T, axis=1)

         A1  A2  A3  A4  B1
0       NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1       NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
Weights NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Unexpected Behavior:
if I take the exact same but use `.values` it works.

```
vals.mul(multiply_vals.T.values, axis=1)

    A1    A2    A3   A4    B1
0  0.0  0.25  2.25  4.0  0.66
1  0.5  0.50  2.25  2.0  0.33
```

Why does `.values` work?
Using pandas version `'0.25.0'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need the values from multiply vals

`vals * multiply_vals.values.T`

```
    A1    A2    A3   A4    B1
0  0.0  0.25  2.25  4.0  0.66
1  0.5  0.50  2.25  2.0  0.33
```

Comment: This is a good alternative as well! It still goes NULL when we don't use `.values` though. very strange!

Comment: using `.values` returns a `np.array` which will cause `*` to do element-wise multiplication

Answer (score 2):

Define the second one as a `Series` as it is only one column, then multiply by its transpose:

```
import pandas as pd
vals = pd.DataFrame({'A1':[0,1], 'A2':[1,2], 'A3':[3,3],'A4':[4,2],'B1':[2,1]})
multiply_vals = pd.Series([.5,.25,.75,1,.33], index=['A1','A2','A3','A4','B1'])
vals*multiply_vals.T
    A1    A2    A3   A4    B1
0  0.0  0.25  2.25  4.0  0.66
1  0.5  0.50  2.25  2.0  0.33
```

Comment: Ah - the *why* might have something to do with `Series` versus `DataFrame`. Very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd
vals = pd.DataFrame({'A1':[0,1], 'A2':[1,2], 'A3':[3,3],'A4':[4,2],'B1':[2,1]})
multiply_vals = pd.DataFrame({'Weights':[.5,.25,.75,1,.33]}, index=['A1','A2','A3','A4','B1'])
vals2 = vals.transpose()
vals2.columns =['0', '1']
df_join = pd.merge(vals2, multiply_vals, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df_join['0 weighted'] = df_join['0']*df_join['Weights']
df_join['1 weighted'] = df_join['1']*df_join['Weights']
df_final = df_join[['0 weighted', '1 weighted']]
df_final = df_final.transpose()
df_final.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason [DataFrame.mul](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) and [DataFrame.multiply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.multiply.html) don't work as expected is that they are referencing the names of the columns *and* rows to do elementwise operations. This is very useful for other purposes.

Converting to a Series with `vals.mul(multiply_vals.T.values, axis=1)`

or `vals * multiply_vals.values.T` solves the original problem.

However, if you want to make [DataFrame.mul](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) to work, you could do this:

Starting with the same DataFrames...

```
vals = pd.DataFrame({'A1':[0,1], 'A2':[1,2], 'A3':[3,3],'A4':[4,2],'B1':[2,1]})
multiply_vals = pd.DataFrame({'Weights':[.5,.25,.75,1,.33]}, index=['A1','A2','A3','A4','B1'])
```

We need to reshape `multiply_vals` to match the expected shape.

```
# copying the rows, in a somewhat silly exercise
multiply_vals_reshaped = pd.concat([multiply_vals.T, multiply_vals.T], axis=0)

# matching the index of vals
multiply_vals_reshaped.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

#multiply_vals_reshaped

     A1   A2    A3    A4   B1
  0  0.5  0.25  0.75  1.0  0.33
  1  0.5  0.25  0.75  1.0  0.33
```

`vals.mul(multiply_vals_reshaped)` now behaves as expected:

```
     A1    A2   A3    A4   B1
  0  0.0  0.25  2.25  4.0  0.66
  1  0.5  0.50  2.25  2.0  0.33
```